# create custom jstl tag for spring mvc project

Tags: java, spring, jstl

Is it possible to create custom jstl tag with logic? For example, I want new element (Contact form), where I can put 3 fields (name, email, message) and logic to send this message. 
Usually, a create jsp page, and methods in contoller class, but I repeat it 3 times, and I think, It should be better to create tag with logic.

Answer (score 1):

well, you can. but for what you need, it would be simpler if you create that in a separate jsp page then include it in any page you need.

```html
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/jsp/common/contact.jsp" %>
```